# Serial scammer not banned

Tags: discussion, spam

This user is a repeat spammer.
[Best Place to buy Whisky Online | Exoticwineliquor](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/143898/8697)

Why hasn't he been banned?

Answer (score 6):

Likely due to the moderation strike and Charcoal being offline.

See [Mast's answer for more info.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/391504/310045)

Comment: The majority of us here are not striking.

Comment: @goldilocks, wasnt sure how many here were, but I would say given that most if not all of the mods who are part of the Charcoal project being on strike is a contributing factor, as they tend to be quite proactive in reaching out to other sites to facilitate spammers getting banned.

Comment: It hasn't been applied here much, as far as I can recall, maybe once a year or so (I've been a mod here for seven) someone comes through chat.  The post volume is so low I think most obvious spam gets picked up within a day at most (the delay mostly being after the flag is posted).  I delete or destroy a user if that is their only post.

Answer (score 2):

Done and done.

Moderators on this stack will handle your flags, so please keep flagging. The temporary loss of Charcoal (as pointed out in Dragonrage's answer: https://raspberrypi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2363/19949) is of course a real issue as some posts may slip through unnoticed.

Comment: If spam posts are getting nuked quickly, may be worth asking people to drop a custom mod flag to make sure the account gets nuked as well.

Comment: @Dragonrage thanks for the idea. Not sure if it's worth the effort. As goldilocks has pointed out in the other comment the volume of spam is pretty low. I check all posts by users that are flagged as "spam". Usually its rather unambiguous.